# What do you call the adjective phrase attached to some historical persons? E.g. Erik the Red

Tags: terminology, onomastics

Many historical persons have full names but also a popular adjective phrase attached to them, such as [Eric the Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erik_the_Red) (Erik den Røde in Danish), [Gorm the Old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorm_the_Old) (Gorm den Gamle  in Danish), [Alexander the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_the_Great) etc. I am sure there is a -nym word for this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not one of the -nym words. It's [epithet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet), as per Wikipedia:

> Epithets are sometimes attached to a person's name or appear in place
> of his or her name, as what might be described as a glorified nickname
> or sobriquet, and for this reason some linguists have argued that they
> should be considered as pronouns.[6] It has also been argued that
> epithets are a phenomenon with the syntax-semantics interface, because
> they have components of both, and also a pragmatic dimension.[6]
>
> An epithet is linked to its noun by long-established usage. Not every
> adjective is an epithet. An epithet is especially recognizable when
> its function is largely decorative, such as if "cloud-gathering Zeus"
> is employed other than in reference to conjuring up a storm. "The
> epithets are decorative insofar as they are neither essential to the
> immediate context nor modeled especially for it. Among other things,
> they are extremely helpful to fill out a half-verse", Walter Burkert
> has noted.[7]
>
> Some epithets are known by the Latin term epitheton necessarium, as
> they are required to distinguish the bearers, as an alternative to
> numbers after a prince's name—such as Richard the Lionheart (Richard I
> of England), or Charles the Fat alongside Charles the Bald. The same
> epithet can be used repeatedly joined to different names, such as
> Alexander the Great as well as Constantine the Great.